# missing sound from using code example from three.js side

Tags: three.js

I would like to include audio files in my code but I can't hear anything. to rule out the causes of errors, I made a test setup and only included what was absolutely necessary. the simplest case: simply copy the code from the three.js page directly into the code. but I hear nothing. what's wrong?

```
import * as THREE from "../lib/three/build/three.module.js";
import { OrbitControls } from '../lib/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';


function main() {
    new Main();
}


class Main {
    constructor(){
        this.init();
        this.animate(); 
    }
    
    
    init(){
        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
        this.renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio ); 
        this.renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true; 
        this.renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
        this.renderer.autoClear = false;
        
        this.container = document.getElementById('container');
        this.renderer.setSize(this.container.clientWidth, this.container.clientHeight);
        this.container.appendChild( this.renderer.domElement );

        this.aspect = this.container.clientWidth / this.container.clientHeight; 
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
        this.scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x000000 );
        
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, this.aspect, .1, 10000 );
        this.camera.position.set(300, 0, 0);
    
        this.controls = new OrbitControls( this.camera, this.renderer.domElement );
        this.controls.enableZoom = true;
        this.controls.enabled = true;
        this.controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
    
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        
        var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff,1); 
        this.scene.add(light);


        const listener = new THREE.AudioListener(); 
        this.camera.add( listener );
        
        const sound = new THREE.PositionalAudio( listener ); 
        const audioLoader = new THREE.AudioLoader(); 
        audioLoader.load( 'sounds/noise.ogg', function( buffer ) {  
            sound.setBuffer( buffer );                  
            sound.setRefDistance( 20 );     
            sound.play();
        });
        
        const sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 20, 32, 16 ); 
        const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xff2200 } ); 
        const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( sphere, material ); 
        this.scene.add( mesh );

        mesh.add( sound );
    
    }//end init
    
    
    animate(){
        requestAnimationFrame( this.animate.bind(this) );  
        this.render();
    }//end animate
    
    
    render(){
        
        this.controls.update();
        this.camera.updateMatrixWorld();
        this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix(); 
    

        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera); 
    
    }//end render
    

}//end class


    

export {main};
```

to be sure that the audio file and the path works i just added this to the html for testing:

```
<audio controls>
<source src="sounds/noise.ogg"
</audio>
```

and that works. so what is wrong in the program code? I see the red sphere but i cant here anything. I thought if I take the code directly from the three.js page I can't do much wrong.

Comment: Function main() needs to ba called on user action. For example, mouse click on a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now i got it. that gave me no rest all day. it must not be in the main init or in a constructor of a class. it only works if the whole audio setup is initialized when you press a button "here w". I've updated the code here to serve as an example. the camera looks at the middle and you can move the ball with the "wasd" keys. what a fight

```
import * as THREE from "../lib/three/build/three.module.js";
import { OrbitControls } from '../lib/three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';

function main() {
    new Main();
}

class Main {
    constructor(){
        this.init();
        this.animate(); 
    }
        
    init(){
        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
        this.renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio ); 
        this.renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true; 
        this.renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
        this.renderer.autoClear = false;
        
        this.container = document.getElementById('container');
        this.renderer.setSize(this.container.clientWidth, this.container.clientHeight);
        this.container.appendChild( this.renderer.domElement );

        this.aspect = this.container.clientWidth / this.container.clientHeight; 
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
        this.scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0x000000 );
        
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, this.aspect, .1, 10000 );
        this.camera.position.set(0, 200, -600);
    
        this.controls = new OrbitControls( this.camera, this.renderer.domElement );
        this.controls.enableZoom = true;
        this.controls.enabled = true;
        this.controls.target.set(0, 0, 0);
    
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        
        var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff,1); 
        this.scene.add(light);

        const listener = new THREE.AudioListener(); 
        this.camera.add( listener );
        
        const params = {
         camera: this.camera,
         scene: this.scene,
         listener: listener,
        }
        this.object = new BasicController(params);
    
    
    }//end init
    
    
    animate(){
        requestAnimationFrame( this.animate.bind(this) );  
        this.render();
    }//end animate
    
    
    render(){
        
        this.controls.update();
        this.camera.updateMatrixWorld();
        this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix(); 
    
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera); 
        this.object.Update(0.01);
    
    }//end render
}//end class


class BasicControllerInput {
  constructor() {
    this.Init();    
  }

  Init() {
    this.keys = {
      forward: false,
      backward: false,
      left: false,
      right: false,
      space: false,
      shift: false,
    };
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => this.onKeyDown(e), false);
    document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => this.onKeyUp(e), false);
  }

  onKeyDown(event) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
     case 87: this.keys.forward = true; break; //w
     case 83: this.keys.backward = true; break; //s
     case 65: this.keys.left = true; break; //a
     case 68: this.keys.right = true; break; //d
     case 32: this.keys.space = true; break;
     case 16: this.keys.shift = true; break;
    }
  }

  onKeyUp(event) {
    switch(event.keyCode) {
     case 87: this.keys.forward = false; break;
     case 83: this.keys.backward = false; break;
     case 65: this.keys.left = false; break;
     case 68: this.keys.right = false; break;
     case 32: this.keys.space = false; break;
     case 16: this.keys.shift = false; break;
    }
  }
};//end BasicControllerInput


class BasicController {
  constructor(params) {
    this.Init(params);
  }

  Init(params) {
    this.params = params;
    this.decceleration = new THREE.Vector3(-25.0, -0.0001, -25.0);
    this.acceleration = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0.25, 50.0);
    this.velocity = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);

    this.input = new BasicControllerInput();

        const sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 20, 32, 16 ); 
        const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xff2200 } ); 
        this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh( sphere, material ); 
        
        this.params.scene.add(this.mesh);

        this.soundstate = false;
  }


soundOn(){
/*
const sound = new THREE.Audio( this.params.listener );
const audioLoader = new THREE.AudioLoader(); 
audioLoader.load( 'sounds/noise.ogg', function( buffer ) {  
sound.setBuffer( buffer );  
sound.setLoop( true );  
sound.setVolume( 0.95 );    
sound.play(); 
});
*/

const sound = new THREE.PositionalAudio( this.params.listener );

const audioLoader = new THREE.AudioLoader(); 
audioLoader.load( 'sounds/noise.ogg', function( buffer ) {  
sound.setBuffer( buffer );  
sound.setRefDistance( 500 );    
sound.play(); 
}); 

this.mesh.add( sound );

}




  Update(timeInSeconds) {

    const velocity = this.velocity;
    const frameDecceleration = new THREE.Vector3(
        velocity.x * this.decceleration.x,
        velocity.y * this.decceleration.y,
        velocity.z * this.decceleration.z
    );

    const controlObject = this.mesh;
    const _Q = new THREE.Quaternion();
    const _A = new THREE.Vector3();
    const _R = controlObject.quaternion.clone();

    const acc = this.acceleration.clone();

    if (this.input.keys.forward) {
        velocity.z += acc.z * timeInSeconds;
        if(this.soundstate == false){
            this.soundOn();
            this.soundstate = true;
        }       
    }
    if (this.input.keys.backward) {
        velocity.z -= acc.z * timeInSeconds;
    }
    if (this.input.keys.left) {
    velocity.x -= acc.z * timeInSeconds;   
    }
    if (this.input.keys.right) {
    velocity.x += acc.z * timeInSeconds;
    }   
    
    
    controlObject.quaternion.copy(_R);

    const oldPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
    oldPosition.copy(controlObject.position);

    const forward = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1);
    forward.applyQuaternion(controlObject.quaternion);
    forward.normalize();

    const sideways = new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0);
    sideways.applyQuaternion(controlObject.quaternion);
    sideways.normalize();

    sideways.multiplyScalar(velocity.x * timeInSeconds);
    forward.multiplyScalar(velocity.z * timeInSeconds);

    controlObject.position.add(forward);
    controlObject.position.add(sideways);

    oldPosition.copy(controlObject.position);

  }
  
};//BasicController


export {main};
```